# how to set color in navigation bar in service

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, navigation

I want to set the color in navigation bar, but it is not covering.even i set FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN . how to set the transparent layout in entire screen ,in service . Plz help me?
**This is my code : **

```
View mView = new View(this);
mView.setBackgroundColor(shared.getColor());

    // get the WindowManager for the context-specific Display
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    // create the LayoutParams for the new Window
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,//width
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,//height
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,//xpos // TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT is denied in apiLevel >=19
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,// flags
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT //formats // the pixel format, here: translucent
    );
    wm.addView(mView, params);
```

[image]

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to change view from service.. what you are doing considered annoying by many users.. Please try to use another approach if you trying to alert your users..

Comment: can u plz suggest me ,what is other approach are der for color fliter the view like service?

Comment: Hi @lisha , did you find a solution for this?

Comment: no, do you knw the solution

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below......

```
View mView = new View(this);
mView.setBackgroundColor(shared.getColor());

// get the WindowManager for the context-specific Display
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

// create the LayoutParams for the new Window
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
int max = Math.max(getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());
params.type = TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
    params.height = max + 200;
    params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
wm.addView(mView, params);



//getting screen height and width
public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}
public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```